# Looking for how to convert dataframe of numbers from objects to floats

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:
[image: dataframe]

I got the data by scrapping a basketball website but all the datatypes of the columns are objects instead of floats. I tried but splitting up the dataframe to only the numeric columns to do `.astype(float)` but I get an error. I just need help converting the proper columns into floats instead of objects.

Can't use `.astype(float)` cause the column has numbers that start with **`.`** .

[image: column example]

How to remove the extra `0`'s?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!!! I ask that when asking a question, put a minimum reproducible example, for a better understanding of what you want and the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to change specific columns into a float

```
df[['column1', 'column2']] = df[['column1', 'column2']].astype(float)
```

Comment: I get an error with the column that has a "." at the start of the string

Comment: Can you update your original question to provide an example?

Comment: There I update the question

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the error? I just tried to recreate it on my end and it works correctly for me

Comment: I get ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' '

Comment: Oh that is probably because you are trying to convert an empty string to a float. If you don't care that '' be replaced with a 0 you could do: df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x : x.replace('', 0)) then apply the originally applied code

Comment: is there any way to keep the . instead of replacing it with a 0 or can it be changed back once I convert to a float?

Comment: Once you change it to 0 and then apply the "astype" part of the code it should change it to 0.0

Comment: Is there a way to delete the extra 0's I posted a new screenshot

Comment: You can apply a round at this point. df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x : x.round(2)) #You can replace 2 with however deep you would like the data to be rounded. Take note though that this is not the standard rounding that you would think of for information on a deeper understanding of pythonic round please look up bankers rounding

Comment: Is there a way with rounding as I don't want the numbers to change just remove the zeros

Comment: df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x : format(x, ".2f"))

Answer (score 0):

Use this pd.to_numeric with errors='ignore':

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

Here is a MCVE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Letters':[*'ABCD'],
                   'Numbers':[1,2,3,4],
                   'Decimals':[.1,.2,.3,.4],
                   'String Numbers':['1', '.2', '1.5', '.04'],
                   'Words':'Dog Jane Tom Cat'.split(' ')})
    
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

Output:

```
  Letters  Numbers  Decimals  String Numbers Words
0       A        1       0.1            1.00   Dog
1       B        2       0.2            0.20  Jane
2       C        3       0.3            1.50   Tom
3       D        4       0.4            0.04   Cat

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------          --------------  -----  
 0   Letters         4 non-null      object 
 1   Numbers         4 non-null      int64  
 2   Decimals        4 non-null      float64
 3   String Numbers  4 non-null      float64
 4   Words           4 non-null      object 
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 288.0+ bytes
```